# PHP Artisan Custom Command

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I need a custom command in my php artisan.

I have created the command file via artisan shell.

But when I execute it via php artisan it throws it as undefined.

It is also confusing for me how to add arguments to my command.

Here is my whole command file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;

class createLibrarySet extends Command
{

/**
 * The console command name.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $name = 'createLibrarySet';

/**
 * The console command description.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $description = 'Creates a Library Set.';

/**
 * Create a new command instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

/**
 * Execute the console command.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function fire()
{
    $dir = mkdir(app_path()."/".library."/".$this->library_name);
    $coreName = $this->library_name;
    $serivceProvider = $coreName."."."ServiceProvider.php";
    $library = $coreName."."."Library.php";
    $facade = $coreName."."."Facade.php";
    $interface = $coreName."."."Interface.php";
    fopen($dir."/".$library, "w");
    fopen($dir."/".$facade, "w");
    fopen($dir."/".$serivceProvider, "w");
    fopen($dir."/".$interface, "w");
}

/**
 * Get the console command arguments.
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function getArguments()
{
    return array(
        array('example', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'An example argument.'),
    );
}

/**
 * Get the console command options.
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function getOptions()
{
    return array(
        array('example', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'An example option.', null),
    );
}

}
```

Comment: Why are you doing all those fopen() calls and then failing to capture the file handle? If you intend to actually write to those files, you'll need the filehandle to do so, and you're losing all of them.

Comment: no that section is incomplete and is not my concern, I'm concerned with artisan interface now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the command to your `app/start/artisan.php`:

```
Artisan::resolve('createLibrarySet');
```

Now you should be able to see in the

```
php artisan
```

listing.

To get your arguments, you just have to:

```
$email = $this->argument('email');
```

And options

```
$force = $this->option('force');
```

Comment: may I ask how then I can get the arguments passed in the shell? currently I have only one argument which is "example" but I don't really know how to get its value