# Generate Artisan command instead of "php artisan serve"

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

I want to make an alias like

`php artisan go`

instead of

`php artisan serve`

I will appreciate any other idea :-) .I also read this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan#generating-commands) and search a lot but it wasn't so clear and other questions were about making `class` or `.env` files and etc.

Thanks in advance

**Update**
This question is not duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22865671/php-artisan-custom-command) because it's not contain calling `php artisan` itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Artisan Custom Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22865671/php-artisan-custom-command)

Comment: this is not duplicate because that question doesn't contains calling `artisan` itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create the command using:

```
php artisan make:command GoCommand
```

Add this in the class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput;

class GoCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'go';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command description';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $output = new ConsoleOutput;
        $output->writeln("Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8000>");
        Artisan::call('serve');
        Artisan::output();
    }
}
```

Use the command:

```
php artisan go
```

Visit: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

and see the output in your console.

Comment: Sorry I can't upvote your answer because of my daily vote limit. I will do it tomorrow. it works but how can I print output like this `Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8000>
`

Comment: @GameO7er take a look at my edited class. Make sure you mark the answer, don't know if that part of the limit as well :) happy coding!

Comment: I did mark :-) . It works like a charm :-) thanks a billion @nakov